# std::list Iterator doesn't get assigned

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, variable-assignment, ambiguity

Sorry about the vague question title, but I have these typedefs here:

```
typedef std::list<AnimationKeyframe> Timeline;
typedef Timeline::iterator Keyframe;
```

and let's say a class like this:

```
class foo
{
Timeline timeline;
Keyframe left,right;
};
```

I also have a copy/assignment constructor because I'm storing iterators (a bad idea it seems),
and the trouble lies just there.

```
Keyframe myTemp, hisTemp;
this->left = this->timeline.begin(); // assigns
myTemp = this->timeline.begin(); // assigns
hisTemp = that.timeline.begin() // does not assign
```

as soon as I am trying to assign a Keyframe with one of 'that' (the other foo) I get errors that look like an ambiguity problem.

> binary '=' : no operator found which
>   takes a right-hand operand of type
>   'std::_List_const_iterator<_Mylist>'
>   (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Additional info:

```
  with
 [
     _Mylist=std::_List_val<AnimationKeyframe,std::allocator<AnimationKeyframe>>
 ]
  could be 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist> &std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>::operator =(const std::_List_iterator<_Mylist> &)'
 with
 [
     _Mylist=std::_List_val<AnimationKeyframe,std::allocator<AnimationKeyframe>>
 ]
 while trying to match the argument list '(Keyframe, std::_List_const_iterator<_Mylist>)'
 with
 [
     _Mylist=std::_List_val<AnimationKeyframe,std::allocator<AnimationKeyframe>>
 ]
```

What causes this odd behavior?
I'm suspecting my bad style for using iterators as states...but I don't know how else I could do, aside from keeping pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks as though `that` is `const` (perhaps a const reference). `begin() const` returns a `const_iterator`, not an `iterator`.

The reason there is no conversion from const_iterator to iterator is as follows:

```
void foo(const std::vector<int> &vec) {
    std::vector<int>::iterator it = vec.begin(); // if this compiled...
    *it = 5;  // then this would attempt to modify a vector taken by const ref
}
```